# eclipse PDT, how to run a PHP script in CLI mode

Tags: php, eclipse

I installed Eclipse IDE PHP-2020-06. I configure it with a existing PHP executable. When I run (not debug) a simple PHP script in CLI mode, the debugger perspective always opens. I don't want that. I want to run my CLI script not debug it. How to do that ?

edit 2010-09-11 : i close the question. I don't know why but today the problem is no more.